# How to collectively refer to Followers and Following?

Tags: navigation, tabs, names

In an application I’m working on we have a user profile which has currently two tabs — **Followers** and **Following**. This lists the people that are following the user and list of people that the user is following.

In an effort to make the interface more compact I would like to have one tab with sub-navigation (using pills) of **Followers** and **Following**. However, I can’t really find a good name for this parent tab? I thought about subscriptions? But has anybody got any better ideas?

Comment: Lists? Users? People?

Comment: People sounds good, but if you want to stress that there is a relation to those people, how about "Network". The people following you and the people you follow do after all constitute a network of people (Hey, did I say "people" already?)

Comment: @MarjanVenema *Network* sounds like a good choice unless there's a chance it might be confused with networking in regards to computers.

Answer (score 3):

How about **Connections** ?

It implies a link to the user, but doesn't qualify whether it's a follower or someone you're following.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of options here. I prefer the ones that stress the human aspect of it.

**"People"** would be my choice. "Contacts" is another option I'd consider if it makes sense in context. An alternative is "Users", but it sounds off to my ear.

Comment: **People** wouldn’t really be appropriate, it doesn’t really describe — Followers/Following. Sure, the **People** are *following*, but it doesn’t describe what it is in general. I just went with **Subscriptions** in the end. But thanks for your suggestion anyway.